# HTML href not working

Tags: html

I am hoping that I've just made a simple mistake on what should be a very simple bit of HTML. The issue is that this below example the frame targets work for "main.php", "phpinfo.php" and "awstats/awstats.pl?config=Stormwind". However, the links "https://stormwind:10000" and "phpmyadmin/index.php" insist on opening in a new window. Am I just missing something?

```
<ul>
<li><a href="main.php" target="main_window">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="https://stormwind:10000" target="main_window">Webmin</a>    </li>
<li><a href="phpmyadmin/index.php" target="main_window">PHP MyAdmin</a></li>
<li><a href="phpinfo.php" target="main_window">PHP Info</a></li>
<li><a href="awstats/awstats.pl?config=Stormwind" target="main_window">Awstats</a></li>
<li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about" target="main_window">About</a></li>
</ul>
<base target="main_window">
<iframe src="main.php" height="100%" width="100%" name="main_window">      </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with _parent instead of main window?

Comment: Using _parent makes it take over the whole window. I want it to open in the "main_window" frame like, for example, the "phpinfo.php" does.

Comment: It could be that your page is http where your links are https?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">
```

I hope you understand it ;-)

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

~ adagi

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It was a configuration issue with webmin itself. By default it will not work with iframe. You need to enable in it's config file:

no_frame_options=1

Then restart web min.